# Curl error connection reset by peer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, peer

I have a problem when I want to call an api which is config in my vendor file, Yesterday that worked and all was fine but now i can't make any call and I have this error "Curl Error, connection reset by peer'.

I'm in laravel project and i call my Api with that command :

```
$api = new ItemFamily($url,$user,$password)
$data = $api->call()
```

Answer (score 0):

The "connection reset by peer" error in cURL typically indicates that the remote server or endpoint has closed the connection unexpectedly, usually due to some error or issue on their side.

In Laravel, you may encounter this error when making HTTP requests using the built-in GuzzleHTTP library or other HTTP clients. To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Verify the remote endpoint
2. Check your server logs
3. Increase the timeout value
4. Check for network issues
5. Test with a different HTTP client